# The same output of the Queue object in browser console after manipulations with it

Tags: javascript, queue

Please check the code bottom (the Queue JS)
in Codepen and here in snippet everything is good, but in browser console _stoage in both outputs has 2 elements.
Can someone explain why?

I tried to save my newQueue object in a variable, and then use this variable in console.log, but the result always the same.

```js
class Queue {
  constructor(){
    this._newestElement = 1,
    this._oldestElement = 1,
    this._storage = {}
  }
  size() {
    return this._newestElement-this._oldestElement
  }
  enqueue (data) {
    this._storage[this._newestElement] = data
    this._newestElement++
  }
  dequeue () {
    let deletedData;
    if (this._newestElement !== this._oldestElement){
      deletedData = this._storage[this._oldestElement]
      delete this._storage[this._oldestElement]
      this._oldestElement++
      return deletedData
    }
  }
}
  
let obj1 = {
  id:1,
  value:11
},
    obj2 = {
  id:2,
  value:22
},
    obj3 = {
  id:3,
  value:33
},
    obj4 = {
  id:4,
  value:44
},
    newQueue = new Queue();
newQueue.enqueue(obj1);
newQueue.enqueue(obj2);
newQueue.enqueue(obj3);
newQueue.enqueue(obj4);
console.log(newQueue);
newQueue.dequeue();
newQueue.dequeue();
console.log(newQueue);
```

Comment: this is not the main point of my question. I am trying to figure out how data can be structuring with JS. I got your point (using an Array). But this is totally another story. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome evaluates complex objects at the time of expansion in the console, i.e. when you click the little triangle next to it.

In other words, Chrome shows you the latest state of `newQueue`. You could verify this by doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(newQueue));`

Comment: is there any way to turn off this feature (Chrome shows you the latest state of newQueue)? Thank you

Comment: JSON.stringify(newQueue) - this one is GOOD. But when object will take some weight, in console it will be unreadable at all